# bash : Remove the specific pattern of characters from a line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, tr

The content of the file *a.txt* is :

```
10.39.105.16tcp(1234)   ABCDEF02  
10.49.105.13tcp(521)    ABCDEFV01  
10.19.105.12tcp(1241)   ABCDEFV01  
10.29.105.20tcp(1222)   ABCDEF03  
10.39.104.9tcp(131)     ABCDEF21  
10.49.104.34tcp(1512)   ABCDEF22  
10.89.104.120tcp(1384)  ABCDEF32
```

How to achieve the following output :

```
10.39.105.10 ABCDEF02   
10.49.105.13 ABCDEFV01   
10.19.105.13 ABCDEFV01   
10.29.105.20 ABCDEF03   
10.39.104.1 ABCDEF21   
10.49.104.2 ABCDEF22   
10.89.104.130 ABCDEF32
```

How to remove the pattern **tcp( * )** in every line of the above file ?

Comment: cat a.txt |  cut -d$'\t' -f1 | cut -d$'t' -f1 > 1 and cat a.txt |  cut -d$'\t' -f2 > 2 and paste -d$"\t" 1 2 .. It worked, but I was just curious about achieving it in single command.

Comment: In your example the last numbers in front of tcp has changed as well is that correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed 's/tcp([0-9]\+)\s\+/ /' a.txt
```

That will also get rid of the trailing space after tcp(*) and replace it with a single space as it appears in your output.

To change the actual file (not just the output), add the -i option for inplace:

```
sed -i 's/tcp([0-9]\+)\s\+/ /' a.txt
```

Comment: I've clearly mentioned my attempt in replying to your comment. You can see.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve this might be the answer:

```
    awk '{sub(/tcp(.+)/,"",$1)}1' file

    10.39.105.16 ABCDEF02
    10.49.105.13 ABCDEFV01
    10.19.105.12 ABCDEFV01
    10.29.105.20 ABCDEF03
    10.39.104.9 ABCDEF21
    10.49.104.34 ABCDEF22
    10.89.104.120 ABCDEF32
```